# Catching query suggestions dropdown value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, jquery, 2013, search-box

Next to search box there is a `dropdown` containing query suggestions (everything, people, ...). How can I catch the value of this `dropdown` (it is div.s) in JavaScript (jQuery). Also I want to know which item has been chosen by the user in my JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

You can via javascript set an eventhandler on the dropdown list. You can set the eventhandler to trigger on `.change()` when it's a dropdownlists.

An example would be:

**[In your masterpage]**

```
$("DropDownListClientID").change(function () {
    GetSelectedSearch($(this + " option:selected"))
});
```

**[In your .js file]**

```
function GetSelectedSearch(selection)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. In my js file I send query to search by uing Search Rest API and the result is shown in a div like a mega menu. I wanted to restrict the query by catching the value of this dropdownlist. the problem is this  is not a realy dropdownlist but only divs. I am going to test your answer and will mark it as answer.